# checkcif and PLATON ellipsoid plot: crystall structure does not look right

Tags: visualization-software, crystallographic-information-file

When I open my CIF file in VESTA it looks ok. When I upload it to https://checkcif.iucr.org/, the ellipsoid plot produced by PLATON does not look right. The unit cell of the supercell is not fully packed, some fragments are missing. Has anyone encountered this problem?